# Joomla Custom URL through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla2.5, joomla-sef-urls

My URL: https://domain.com/my-team-league/viewgroup/201-crick

Needed URL: https://domain.com/league/201-crick

Help me to take out of this url issue please

.htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/league/(.+) /my-team-league/viewgroup/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the opposite (and without /):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^my-team-league/viewgroup/(.+) league/$1  [R=302,L]
```

Try with  `[R=302,L]` and after, when that work well, change for `[R=301,L]`

Comment: link is not redirecting.

Comment: Now it's redirecting but gives error: "This webpage has a redirect loop" and return back to same url

Comment: You only use one `.htaccess`, in the root directory, right ?

Comment: You don't have one in `league/` ?

Comment: we have league in url after that id and string is dynamic. The only league is static and remains fixed.

Comment: Which real file you try to open with your link ?

Comment: It's Joomla url structure and SEF is ON from global configurations. Do you asking for real link ?